# Access xinput from acpi bash script on debian

Tags: debian, bash-scripting, acpi

I'm trying to program a non-working special key on my keyboard using the acpi events, and already got acpi to recognize a keypress and pass it on to a shell script. However, for some reason I cannot execute a call to xinput; it always returns with an exit code of 1 and no output. When running the shell script manually it works.

I've also noticed that if I call `xinput --version` I get a correct result calling manually, but when it's called through the acpi, it returns exit code 1 and `Server: failed to open display`, so I guess these are related in some way.

My bash script is quite easy at this moment, but if I can't call xinput, it's rather worthless (as I need to be able to enable/disable using xinput commands).

```
#!/bin/bash
touch="0000006b"

if [ "$3" != $touch ]; then
    # Ignore, not a touchpad event
    echo "$3 is not matching $touch, ignoring"
    exit 0  
fi

# Process event
echo "Got a touchpad keypress"

getTouchDeviceId()
{
    # extract the device id for the supplied touch device name
    xinput list | sed -nr "s|.*$1.*id=([0-9]+).*|\1|p"
}

ENABLEPROP="Device Enabled"
# Get the xinput device number and enabling property for the touchpad
XINPUTNUM=$(getTouchDeviceId "PS/2 Elantech Touchpad")

# Removed the rest
```

I've double checked a lot of things (environment should be ok, it can find the executable), and I know that the code was working at some point (it's based on the code that shipped in [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/acpi-support/download) in the past.

A whoami in the script revealed that it's ran as root, while the desktop environment probably is linked to my regular user account, but I'm not sure how I could fix that...

Edit: When running the xinput as root from a terminal (or running the shell manually as root), it works. When it's called as root through the script activated by the acpi, it's not working.

Would anyone have a suggestion how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xinput needs the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY env variables. 'export' these at the top of the script.

Comment: Thank you! This was effectively what I needed to get it working.